# Django ValidationError

Tags: django, django-forms

According to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/

```
   # Good
   ValidationError(
        _('Invalid value: %(value)s'),
        params={'value': '42'},
   )

   # Bad
   ValidationError(_('Invalid value: %s') % value)
```

The docs doesnt really explain why it is bad / good. Can someone give a concrete example?

Furthermore, when I inspect `form.errors`, I get something like `'Invalid: %(value)s'`. How do I get  the params from the Validation error and interpolate them into the error msg?

**Edited**

So is this considered good?

```
   ValidationError(
        _('Invalid value: %(value)s') % {'value': '42'},
   )
```

I think the real question is: why pass the variables separately via the `params` argument? Why not interpolate directly into the error msg (ignore named or positional interpolation for now)???

***Edited***

Ok, From the source @ https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.5.x/django/forms/forms.py
I don't think there is any way to retrieve ValidationError's params since the Form does ***not*** even save the ValidationError object itself. See code below.

```
class ValidationError(Exception):
    """An error while validating data."""
    def __init__(self, message, code=None, params=None):
        import operator
        from django.utils.encoding import force_text
        """
        ValidationError can be passed any object that can be printed (usually
        a string), a list of objects or a dictionary.
        """
        if isinstance(message, dict):
            self.message_dict = message
            # Reduce each list of messages into a single list.
            message = reduce(operator.add, message.values())

        if isinstance(message, list):
            self.messages = [force_text(msg) for msg in message]
        else:
            self.code = code
            self.params = params
            message = force_text(message)
            self.messages = [message]

class Form:
    ....
    def _clean_fields(...):
       ....
       except ValidationError as e:
            self._errors[name] = self.error_class(e.messages)  # Save messages ONLY
            if name in self.cleaned_data:
                del self.cleaned_data[name]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have multiple parameters, they might appear in a different order when you translate the error message.

Named arguments allow you to change the order in which the arguments appear, without changing `params`. With a tuple of arguments, the order is fixed.

Note that you are linking to the development version of the Django docs. The validation error is not interpolating the parameters because you are using Django 1.5 or earlier. If you try your code in the 1.6 beta, then the parameters are interpolated into the error message.

Comment: If you coerce variables directly into the message, then it's harder to override. For example, you wouldn't be able to use placeholders when using the [`error_messages`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/fields/#error-messages) argument.

Comment: As I've already said, you're looking at the development version of the docs, but you're still copying and pasting code from 1.5.

Answer (score 2):

`ValidationError` is caught by the form validation routine and though it can just show a message, it's better to save the possibility of getting `params` of error; eg. field name, value that caused error and so on. It's stated just before the example you've provided.

> In order to make error messages flexible and easy to override