# Django ValidationError formating in a For Loop

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, error-handling

I've written a series of RegexValidator definitions that I call on django model inputs.  Here is an example:

```
def fein_validator(value):
    err = None
    for validator in FEIN_VALIDATOR:
        try:
            validator(value)
            return value
        except ValidationError as exc:
            err = exc
    raise err
```

For reference the `FEIN_VALIDATOR` for this method is below.  Note that in this example there is only a single item, I have other validators that have multiple items (hence the `for loop`):

```
FEIN_VALIDATOR = [
    RegexValidator(r'^\d{2}-\d{7}$')
    ]
```

The method works perfectly and throws an error when it's supposed to.  But, the error it throws is `Enter a valid value.` and I would like to customize the return to be more specific.

I've tried versions of [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/validation/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17898969/django-validationerror). But these all assume that there is only one pass.  I'm trying to run through a series of validators using a `for loop`.

Question 1:  does the method construction I'm using work for this - or should there be a separate method for each validation? [whereby I can add custom messaging.]

Question 2:  if this does work, how do I change the error message raised to a custom message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT 1: Added comment

Yes, your method work perfect.

EDIT 2: Added custom error message model link

[custom error messages with Model Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436712/custom-error-messages-with-model-form)

```
  def fein_validator(value):
        err = None
        for validator in FEIN_VALIDATOR:
            try:
                validator(value)
                return value
            except ValidationError:
                raise ValidationError({'field_name': ["error message",]})
```

Comment: This throws `TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException`.  I did a little more searching but didn't see why the type error would be thrown... ?

Comment: Throws `AttributeError: 'ValidationError' object has no attribute 'error_list'`.  I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45869212/how-to-properly-throw-a-validationerror-in-django) which makes sense, the error is being thrown from a `Model` which is being populated through a `CreateView` class instance.  I've tried using both the `NON_FIELD_ERRORS` (which is what I would expect to work) and the model field name (`'filed_name'`) - but they both throw the same error.  I'm guessing that my reference to the model field name is wrong - what specifically is the `field_name` reference to?

Comment: After spending more time with the answer above, I realized that there was a bracketing format error (error is now fixed in the answer above) and it works as advertised.  Thanks.